# Splitting a string in python by what follows the split character

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like,

```
s = '1 john 2 james 34 baker 45 discover'
```

I need a list that looks like,

```
split_list = ['1 john', '2 james', '34 baker', '45 discover']
```

I started to do this by using regex split and did not get the desired result,

```
import re
s = '1 john 2 james 34 baker 45 discover'
s = re.split('\d+',s)
print s

['', ' john ', ' james ', ' baker ', ' discover']
```

I guess split does not work since it does not return the splitting pattern. Any clues to do this in a pythonic way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use non capturing lookahead. `(?=\d+)` makes sure that there's a number after the space, but it doesn't include as part of the delimiter.

```
import re
s = '1 john 2 james 34 baker 45 discover'
s = re.split(' (?=\d+)',s)
print s

['1 john', '2 james', '34 baker', '45 discover']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the opposite.

```
s = re.findall('\d+ \w+',s)
```